# How to get li tag attribute data-value and set the value at input tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my example echo:

```
echo '<li data-value="' . $row->id . '"class="option"><img src="' . $row->image . '">' . $row->name . '</li>';
```

So I retrieve the value from database and set the value as li tag data-value.

Jquery:

```
$(".ul_movie2").on('click', 'li', function () {
    var movie_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log(movie_id)
    alert('Text is ' + movie_id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"mymoviemanagement.php",
            data:{data:movie_id},
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                $('#result').val(movie_id);
            }
        });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="result">;
```

This is my input. So at Jquery you can see I set the value to the input, but the input doesn't get the value. The input just show the value only.

Example my value is 84, the input tag show 84, but I inspect element it show me this:

```
<input type="text" value id="result">==$0
```

Which mean I didn't set the value into input tag value, and it only show, not really have value inside.

So how I can get the li attr('data-value') and set the value to input tag?

Answer (score 2):

Two Things:

To get value of the `data-value`, Change this:

```
 var movie_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
```

To this:

```
 var movie_id = $(this).attr('data-value').val();
```

Then set the response this way:

```
 $('#result').innerHTML = movie_id;
```

Your Code is now:

```
 $(".ul_movie2").on('click', 'li', function () {
  var movie_id = $(this).attr('data-value').val();
  console.log(movie_id)
  alert('Text is ' + movie_id);
    $.ajax({
        url:"mymoviemanagement.php",
        data:{data:movie_id},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data) {
            $('#result').html = movie_id;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: $('#result').innerHTML = movie_id; This Where I put?

Comment: I would cange `.attr(‘data-value’)` to `.data(‘value’)`. And why would you go with `$(‘#result’).innerHtml = movie_id` and not `$(‘result’).html(movie_id)`?

Comment: @agrm you are write that it should be .html not innerHTML. I missed that jQuery line with Vanilla JS. I just edited the answer

Comment: @argm `.data(‘value’)` this way also can get the li tag attribut `data-value`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the data-value attribute value just use

```
   $("#result").attr("data-value", movie_id)
```

Comment: Nope, I mean I get value from 'Data-value' attribute, I want to set the value to the input tag value